# removeEventListener not working

Tags: actionscript-3, routes, addeventlistener, event-listener

```
function Drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if ((event.target.parent == InventoryMenu) && (event.target is item)) {
        var picked:item = item(event.target);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Drop);
        InventoryArrowDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, InventoryNav("down"));
        InventoryArrowUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, InventoryNav("up"));

        function Drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if ((event.target.parent == InventoryMenu) && (event.target is item)) {
                var dropped:item = item(event.target);          
                if ((event.target is item) && (event.target.parent == InventoryMenu)) {
                    if (picked.itemdata("workswith") == dropped.name) {
                        var itemname:item = item(FetchResult(picked, dropped));
                        itemname.addChild(itemname.itemdata("filename"));
                        InventoryMenu.removeChild(picked);
                        InventoryMenu.removeChild(dropped);
                        InventoryMenu.addChild(itemname);
                        InventoryUpdate();
                    } else if (picked.name != dropped.name) {
                        trace("No son compatibles");
                    }
                    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Drop);
                    InventoryArrowDown.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, InventoryNav("down"));
                    InventoryArrowUp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, InventoryNav("up"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the removeEventListener on InventoryArrowDown and InventoryArrowUp isn't working. I'm fairly sure the route is correct as it's a direct copy paste from the addEventListener and it uses no variables.

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Following adobe code conventions would make your code a lot easier to read. Method names and instance names should start with a lowercase letter. Class names should start with a uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to help you without seeing the code of `InventoryNav` but maybe the issue is that you should remove the event listeners before your tests.

Also, you should write two different handlers instead of using one and passing an argument like you do.

Here is a modified version of your code that might help:

```
private function drag(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if ((event.target.parent == inventoryMenu) && (event.target is Item)) {
        var picked:Item = Item(event.target);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
        inventoryArrowDown.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inventoryNavDown);
        inventoryArrowUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inventoryNavUp);
    }
}

private function drop(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    inventoryArrowDown.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inventoryNavDown);
    inventoryArrowUp.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, inventoryNavUp);

    if ((event.target.parent == inventoryMenu) && (event.target is Item)) {
        var dropped:Item = Item(event.target);          
        if ((event.target is Item) && (event.target.parent == inventoryMenu)) {
            if (picked.itemdata("workswith") == dropped.name) {
                var itemname:Item = Item(fetchResult(picked, dropped));
                itemname.addChild(itemname.itemdata("filename"));
                inventoryMenu.removeChild(picked);
                inventoryMenu.removeChild(dropped);
                inventoryMenu.addChild(itemname);
                inventoryUpdate();
            } else if (picked.name != dropped.name) {
                trace("No compatible sons");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I came to the exact same conclusion yesterday, its funny. I removed the arguments from the function and moved the removeeventlisteners outside the conditionals. Works perfect!